# I want to Find the number of sales representatives in each city containing at least 2 sales representatives. order by number of employees

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am using the Northwind Database Employees Table.
in picture below: I want to
Find the number of sales representatives in each city containing at least 2 sales representatives. order by number of employees
Using SQL
[Employees Table Northwind Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCZbv.png)

This is my code:[My Code Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kDAS.png)But it is not showing where there are at least two sales representatives instead it display all cities with sales representatives including the cities with only 1.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, what RDBMS are you *really* using? SQL Server and MySQL are *completely* different products

Answer (score 1):

Everything checks about right in your  query and you are just missing a
`HAVING COUNT(*)>=2` clause
Try This

```
SELECT City,COUNT(EmployeeID) AS numofsalesrep
FROM  empolyees
WHERE Title='sales representatives'
GROUP BY City
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
ORDER BY COUNT(EmployeeID)  DESC, City;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT City, COUNT(EmployeeID) AS numofsalesrep  
FROM employees 
WHERE Title = 'sales representative' AND numofsalesrep >= 2 
GROUP BY City
ORDER BY numofsalesrep DESC, City;
```

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on why this works? It might not be clear to everyone how this may solve the original question as it only includes code.

Comment: I have added an AND part in The WHERE clause to filter all rows with numofsalesrep larger than or equal to 2 :-)